# Getting data from recursive function php

Tags: php, recursion

I have a recursive function, but it is only returning the initial data:

```
$urls[] = 'http://site1.com';
$urls[] = 'http://site2.com';
foreach($urls as $url) {
   $output = getMainPage($url, $zids, $listing_count, array(), array());
}
print_r($output); //Line 1
function getMainPage($url, $zids, $listing_count, $ids = array(), $names = array()) {
     $dom = new DOMDocument;
     @$dom->loadHTML($html);
     $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
     $output_html = '';
     foreach ($links as $link){
         print_r($ids); //Line 2
         $ids[] = $this_id;
         $names[] = $this_name;
         $listing_count++;
         if(strpos($href, 'next') !== FALSE) {
             $url = $next_url;
             $o = getMainPage($url, $zids, $listing_count, $ids, $names);
         }
     }
     $output['ids'] = $ids;
     $output['names'] = $names;
     return $output;
}
```

The print_r($output);//line 1 only outputs the initial set of data from the foreach $link loop, however the print_r($ids); //line 2 outputs the incremental ids. So, the output of course is being returned before the loops are finished.

**Edit:** New code (same results, except only the last set of data)

```
$urls[] = 'http://site1.com';
$urls[] = 'http://site2.com';
foreach($urls as $url) {
   $output = getMainPage($url, $zids, $listing_count, array(), array());
}
print_r($output); //Line 1
function getMainPage($url, $zids, $listing_count, $ids = array(), $names = array()) {
     $dom = new DOMDocument;
     @$dom->loadHTML($html);
     $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
     $output_html = '';
     foreach ($links as $link){
         print_r($ids); //Line 2
         $output['ids'][] = $this_id;
         $output['$names'][] = $this_name;
         $listing_count++;
         $output['listing_count'] = $listing_count;
         if(strpos($href, 'next') !== FALSE) {
             $url = $next_url;
             $output = getMainPage($url, $output['zids'], $output['listing_count'], $output['ids'], $output['names']);
         }
     }

     return $output;
}
```

Comment: `$o = getMainPage($url, $zids, $listing_count, $ids, $names);` the `$o` is never used somewhere else..

Comment: @BagusTesa I reworked it, thinking about what you mentioned, and still same results. See edited code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$urls[] = 'http://site1.com';
$urls[] = 'http://site2.com';
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $output = getMainPage($url, $zids, $listing_count, array(), array());
}
print_r($output); //Line 1

function getMainPage($url, $zids, $listing_count, $ids = array(), $names = array(), $o = array()) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $output_html = '';
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        print_r($ids); //Line 2
        $output['ids'][] = $this_id;
        $output['$names'][] = $this_name;
        $listing_count++;
        $output['listing_count'] = $listing_count;
        $o[] = $output;
        if (strpos($href, 'next') !== FALSE) {
            $url = $next_url;
            $o = getMainPage($url, $output['zids'], $output['listing_count'], $output['ids'], $output['names'], $o);
        }
    }

    return $o;
}
```

Comment: This goes back to just returning the initial set of data

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working:

```
$urls[] = 'http://site1.com';
$urls[] = 'http://site2.com';
foreach($urls as $url) {
   $output = getMainPage($url, $zids, $listing_count, array(), array());
}
print_r($output); //Line 1
function getMainPage($url, $zids, $listing_count, $ids = array(), $names = array()) {
 $dom = new DOMDocument;
 @$dom->loadHTML($html);
 $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
 $output_html = '';
 foreach ($links as $link){
     print_r($ids); //Line 2
     $output['ids'][] = $this_id;
     $output['$names'][] = $this_name;
     $listing_count++;
     $output['listing_count'] = $listing_count;
     if(strpos($href, 'next') !== FALSE) {
         $url = $next_url;
         $o = getMainPage($url, $output['zids'], $output['listing_count'], $output['ids'], $output['names']);
         $output['ids'] = array_merge($output['ids'], $o['ids']);
         $output['names'] = array_merge($output['names'], $o['names']);
     }
 }

 return $output;
```

}